# python's 'connect_ex' equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to check whether an address is available for connection in C++.

In python it's quite simple, I make a socket and call 'connect_ex' like so:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
res = s.connect_ex((other_host,other_port))
if res == 0:
    print("connection available")
```

Is there a C++ equivalent to this?

Comment: There's a sockets API available (in c) for various OSs you can use. Sockets aren't part of the c++ standard library facilities though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - thank you for replying!  could you link me to additional information regarding this API? perhaps a code snippet?

Comment: Python's also written in C, so you could re-use its own code in your program or at least study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `connect_ex` is actually C/C++ `connect`. Both Python `connect` and `connect_ex` do essentially the same, i.e. connecting to the given peer. The only difference is that `connect` throws an exception if the connection fails while `connect_ex` simply returns an error.

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect_ex):

> Like connect(address), **but return an error indicator instead of raising an exception** for errors returned by the C-level connect() call (other problems, such as “host not found,” can still raise exceptions). The error indicator is 0 if the operation succeeded, otherwise the value of the errno variable. This is useful to support, for example, asynchronous connects.

Since C/C++ don't raise an exception on `connect`, they are more like `connect_ex` in the first place. There is no need to have an extra function for what the original function is already doing.

Looking [at the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dc516ef8395d15da0ab225eb0dceb2e0581f51ca/Modules/socketmodule.c#L3203) you will see that both `connect` and `connect_ex` essentially call `internal_connect`, either with `raise=1` or `raise=0`. And `internal_connect` is doing C `connect`.

Comment: great answer- thank you for the detailed explanation!